# Null pointer exception with linked hashmap

Tags: java

Crashlytics is showing a few crashes on the following line:

```
if(appObj.getStationsList().get(tag)!=null){
```

`getStationsList()` returns a `LinkedHashMap<String, StationInfo>`. How can I avoid getting this error? It's ironic that my very check to avoid this error actually resulted in it.

Comment: `appObj.getStationsList()` is `null` and you're not checking that...

Comment: or `appObj` is `null` and there's no check for that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check:

```
if(appObj.getStationsList()==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if(appObj.getStationsList().get(tag)!=null){
```

with

```
 if(appObj.getStationsList() !=null && appObj.getStationsList().get(tag)!=null){

}
```

Comment: This line is symbolic Object obj = appObj.getStationsList();  Object should be replaced with station and also must be upcast while getting

Comment: see edited answer and remove downcast vote

Comment: When providing answers, provide compilable code or post that you're showing pseudocode.

Comment: Are you giving me orders or what?